# Repeating a function indefinitely, preferably without using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am building a slide show framework and was having trouble figuring out the best way to cycle the animation function, I know I could use `setInterval()` but was wondering if there was a better way to repeat it without being to resource intensive.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
class slideShow {
    constructor(imgDir, dataList) {
        this.imgDir = imgDir;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.settings = 0;
        this.imgList = 0;
        this._init();
    }
    _init(){
        $.getJSON(`${this.imgDir}/${this.dataList}.json`, (data)=>{
            this.settings = data.settings;
            this.imgList = data.imgList;
        })
    }
    start(){
        for(let img of this.imgList){
            $(this.settings.selector).fadeOut(this.settings.fadeTime, ()=>{
                $(this.settings.selector).attr("src",`${this.imgDir}/${img}`);
                $(this.settings.selector).fadeIn(this.settings.fadeTime);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "settings":{
        "selector":"#slideShow",
        "fadeTime":1000
    },
    "imgList":[
        "slide_01.jpg",
        "slide_02.jpg",
        "slide_03.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with `setInterval()` ?

Comment: `setInterval` has _lots_ of problems, and in any event (no pun intended) shouldn't be mixed with jQuery animations

Comment: Are you trying to wait for current image to complete animation before next image begins animation at `for..of` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to pseudo-recursively loop from the "completion callback" of the final step of the animation.

```
start() {
    var current = 0;
    (function loop() {
        let img = imgList[current++];
        current %= imgList.length;
        let $sel = $(this.settings.selector);
        $sel.fadeOut(this.settings.fadeTime, () => {
            $sel.attr("src",`${this.imgDir}/${img}`);
            $sel.fadeIn(this.settings.fadeTime, loop); // <-- here
        });
    })();
}
```

Note that I've removed the `for ... of` loop - each pass of the `loop` function here just handles one frame of the slideshow.

This would resolve what appears to be a bug in your original code, where you'd get three consecutive `fadeOut` animations (two of which would of course be invisible) because nothing in your code allows for the first cycle of `fadeOut, change image, fadeIn` to complete before the next iteration of the `for ... of` loop starts.

Comment: This worked, though i had to add a `that = this`. Also, thank you for pointing out the bug.

Comment: Ironic - I've just had a long chat with the other answerer about the correct handling of `this` and didn't spot the bug in my own answer :)

Comment: the alternative would be to dereference the selector and settings values outside of the `loop`, since they're the only variables that depend on `this`.  Oh, and the `imgDir` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.then()`, jQuery `.promise()`, recursion

```
class slideShow {
    constructor(imgDir, dataList) {
        this.imgDir = imgDir;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.settings = 0;
        this.imgList = 0;
        this._init();
    }
    _init(){
        $.getJSON(`${this.imgDir}/${this.dataList}.json`, (data)=>{
            this.settings = data.settings;
            this.imgList = data.imgList;
        }).then(this.start)
    }
    start(){
        for(let img of this.imgList){
            $(this.settings.selector).fadeOut(this.settings.fadeTime, ()=>{
                $(this.settings.selector).attr("src",`${this.imgDir}/${img}`);
                $(this.settings.selector).fadeIn(this.settings.fadeTime);
            });
        }
        $(this.settings.selector).promise()
        .then(() => this.start() /* or this._init() */)
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't "real" recursion, because the event loop gets to unwind the stack before the `.then` callback gets called

Comment: @Alnitak Ok. What should the process be termed? Your approach is probably what OP is looking for at animation portion. Not certain if OP wants animations in sequential order? If yes, would substitute `.queue()`, `$,map()` for `for..of` loop

Comment: Your `.then(this.start)` is wrong too, it should be `.then(() => this.start)` since otherwise you've got an undefined `this`

Comment: I always call it psuedo-recursion

Comment: @Alnitak Why would `this` be `undefined`? A function is being referenced outside of `for..of` loop. `.then(() => this.start)` would not call `this.start`,  but reference `this.start`, yes? Was not aware of the term "pseudo-recursion", or that there was a difference. Will consider asking a Question concerning the same; though not sure how to formulate the text of the Question?

Comment: `this` is undefined because when `start` gets called the second time it hasn't been called using the standard function call mechanism so `this` becomes unbound.  I also made a typo myself - it should read `.then(() => this.start())`

Comment: @Alnitak _"`this` is undefined because when `start` gets called the second time it hasn't been called using the standard function call mechanism."_ Now am confused. Also,  since `Promise`, `.then()` sets `this` to `window`, would not `this` be `window` within `.then()` at `.then(() => this.start())` at your previous comment?

Comment: No, because the arrow function binds `this` to whatever it is in the outer scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127228/discussion-between-guest271314-and-alnitak).