# What are the boundaries of recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, language-agnostic, computer-science

Given

```
let doAsynchronousStuff = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("abcdefg"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)])
    }, Math.PI * 1 + Math.random())
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(doAsynchronousStuff)
}
```

Is the pattern an implementation of

- recursion;
- tail-call optimization;
- iteration;
- a non-terminating procedure that happens to refer to itself;

or; other common pattern that is not listed above?

Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

Comment: TCO is a property of a runtime/compiler, not the code. So the TCO item is simply not applicable (until it's re-worded).

Comment: @zerkms Seeking clarity as to the differences of the terms listed, and what term should pattern at Question be referenced as; to avoid confusion. Can you post an Answer to Question?

Comment: It is every of 1,3,4.

Comment: @zerkms _"It is every of 1,3,4."_ Ok, can you place that in an Answer, with details of why as to each of 1, 3, 4?

Comment: I don't see how classification of a random piece of code is useful. Giving an arbitrary piece of code a dedicated name makes unnecessary noise.

Comment: @zerkms Have been communicated to that the pattern is _not_ recursion. Yet, you promptly communicated that the pattern _is_ recursion. Which communication is accurate?

Comment: Well, it definitely is recursion, because it clearly invokes itself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Indirect_recursion

Comment: @zerkms _"Well, it is recursion, because it clearly invokes itself."_ See closed Question [What is pseudo-recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390979/what-is-pseudo-recursion?noredirect=1&lq=1). The Question was poorly formed. Attempted to post only the basic Question, here. Re-inspired by this Question [What does it mean to implement recursively or iteratively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498620/what-does-it-mean-to-implement-recursively-or-iteratively)

Comment: I don't see how the "call stack must grow" or "it must be synchronous" is a requirements for a function to be recursive.

Comment: @zerkms Ok. Can you settle the matter, here? Is wikipedia a credible source?

Comment: "Is wikipedia a credible source?" --- it depends. In this question I trust it. Mostly because I don't know any more trustworthy source.

Comment: @zerkms Wikipedia can be edited, similar to MDN; see [Is it possible to display an .html document , or .html fragment at CSS content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content).

Comment: *Conceptually* it should certainly be recursive. Whether the computer science definition of "recursion" is different from the common sense definition I don't know. I think that *implementation* details (such as TCO) shouldn't have any impact, otherwise the "recursiveness" of code would change depending on which engine executes the code. But that's my personal opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the code eliminating all non relevant stuff and using a style I feel is more readable and appeasing in this context.

```
function doAsynchronousStuff()
{
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
   {
      setTimeout(() => {resolve("test")}, 0)
   })
  .then(console.log)
  .then(doAsynchronousStuff);
}
```

We should analyze the execution flow remembering that JS has [an event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop), particularly

- `setTimeout` posts its argument function to be executed on the next<sup>1</sup> cycle of the event loop.
- `then` posts its argument function to be executed on the next cycle of the event loop.

The existence of the event loop is important because the function posting message onto it *run-to-completion* before the loop is re-entered.

Also a good knowledge of promises is required, for example knowing that `then` returns a new promise.

When `doAsynchronousStuff` is executed the `Promise` object is constructed and its argument function is called immediately.

```
Execution stack                      Event loop messages

doAsynchronousStuff
Promise constructor
Closure (resolve, reject)
```

This is in turn calls `setTimeout` that post an event and returns.

```
Execution stack                      Event loop messages

doAsynchronousStuff                  resolve("test")
Promise constructor
Closure (resolve, reject)
setTimeout
```

The execution falls back to `doAsynchronousStuff` that set the continuations for the `Promise` objects but doesn't execute them of course. So in the end `doAsynchronousStuff` returns and we have a *run-to-completion* situation.

```
Execution stack                      Event loop messages

                                     resolve("test")
```

The event loop executes `resolve("test")` (or better the closure that contains it) which set the promise as resolved and schedule its continuation on the next cycle

```
 Execution stack                      Event loop messages

 resolve                              console.log
```

`resolve` ends we have again a *run-to-completion* situation.

```
 Execution stack                      Event loop messages

                                      console.log
```

`console.log` is executed. Actually, a function that calls `console.log` is executed, this function is set by the promise object when `then` is called.
When `console.log` returns its promise resolves and the `doAsynchronousStuff` is posted on the event loop.

```
 Execution stack                      Event loop messages

 resolve                              doAsynchronousStuff
```

When `resolve` ends we have a *run-to-completion* and `doAsynchronousStuff` is executed once again.

---

Now I won't dig too much in the mathematical sense nor in the CS theoretical sense of the terms in the list in your question, doing such would have no practical benefits as I don't believe this is a theoretical question.
I will instead limit myself to a programming point of view.

By the time the second `doAsynchronousStuff` instance is called the first one is long gone (it *run-to-completion*).
Basically the situation is equivalent to doing this

```
let f = () => { console.log('hi!'); setTimeout(f, 0); }
```

I **wouldn't call this function recursive** since recursion implies a destruction of a problem into smaller auto-similar parts.
A recursive function doesn't have to call itself directly or doesn't have to "make the stack grow" but it must be *defined in terms of itself*.

If it were like

```
let f = () => { f(); }
```

I'd call it (badly) recursive. So what is it?
I'd like to say that a function is recursive in the programming sense if you can't complete it without completing all the calls to itself it makes.
The first example can be completed without waiting for the subsequent invocations of `f` to complete, the second one instead cannot.
In my mind I call the first version of `f`, *scheduled*.

Regarding **tail-call optimization**, it has nothing to do with this.
[TCO transform a particular kind of recursion into a loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), it is a compiler optimization not a property of the code.
The *tail-call* is a property of the code, but this code is not *tail-call* as it is not recursive in the first place.

It is also **not iteration** in the programming sense (while in the theoretical sense it is) since *iteration* is achieved with specific constructs (like `for`, `while`, `goto`).
The boundary is blurry here as iteration, recursion and scheduling overlaps.

Finally this is certainly the case of **a non-terminating procedure that happens to refer to itself**.

---

<sup>1</sup> We make a simplification here, it has not to be the *very next* cycle, it is just a future cycle.

Comment: _"I wouldn't call this function recursive"_ Does that mean "No, the pattern is not recursive; not recursion"? As noted by @zerkms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499044/what-are-the-boundaries-of-recursion/40504969#comment68242216_40499044 _"Indirect recursion occurs when a function is called not by itself but by another function that it called (either directly or indirectly). For example, if f calls f, that is direct recursion, but if f calls g which calls f, then that is indirect recursion of f."_ Should wikipedia be edited? Or use NTPTHTRTI as description of pattern?

Comment: @guest271314 My point is that `doAsynchronousStuff` doesn't call itself (nor directly nor indirectly), it just sets things up so that it will be called  (by the JS engine) later once again. This is different from a call. Anyway that's how *I* interpret the code. If you are looking for a taxonomy of code patterns you may find yourself disappointed. The formal definition of recursion/iteration is much more involved and require a steering into logic. I interpreted the answer from a *programming* pov, where *recursion* is meant in the common, informal, sense. BTW, I call that pattern "scheduling".

Comment: Can you include a recursive pattern with description at your answer, for comparison and disambiguation?

Comment: @guest271314 Do you mean something like the ol' good Fibonacci serie? `fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); f(0) = f(1) = 1` implemented, say, as `function f(n){ return n <= 1 ? 1 : f(n-1) + f(n-2); }`. This can be turned into a [TC recursion](https://benignbemine.github.io/2015/07/19/es6-tail-calls/).

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. The code in question is not recursive, not quite iterative (though from the point of view of the English language it is iterative, from the point of view of what we *normally* call iterative in programming it is not, note that from the point of view of the English language recursion is iterative but we don't say that it is in programming), since it is not recursive the phrase "tail-call-optimised" does not apply and it is not non terminating since the function ends with a return.

What it is is a function that schedules a series of functions to execute at a later time one of which is itself.

Scheduling **is** a design pattern. One of the oldest example of **scheduling** is process scheduling that operating systems do. One of the next oldest example is cron.

How scheduling works is that the run-time environment (Linux kernel, Windows kernel, the cron process, javascript) saves a "database" (which may be as simple as a linked-list or as high level as SQL or as low-tech as a text file) of some sort of reference to the code that it is supposed to run and conditions that trigger them (check out AWS Lambda service for a very high-level implementation of this idea) and periodically somehow checks to see if the condition is met then execute the code.

For OS kernels the set of conditions includes some sort of fairness algorithm to ensure that all programs get to use the CPU. For cron the condition is the time specification in crontab. For javascript the condition is the event that the callback is registered with (for setTimeout it is the timeout event).

Traditionally, if you were to write your own software for this you'd write it as a simple state machine. The following is C-like pseudocode implementing the same thing as your example above

```
int tick = 0;

// Assume that there is an API for registering 1ms periodic interrupt
interrupt_1ms periodic () {
    tick++;
}

int main (void) {
    int timeout = PI + rand(); // a fairly silly way to randomly select 3 or 4 ms
    char state = 0;
    char result = nul;
    char* data = "abcdefg";

    while (1) {
        if (tick >= timeout && state == 0) {
            state = 1;
            tick = 0;
            timeout = PI + rand();
        }

        switch (state) {
            case 1:
                result = data[floor(rand() * 7)];
                state = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("%c", result);
                state = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                state = 0; // reschedule the doAsynchronousStuff
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

That's sort of the traditional way. What javascript does is not exactly the same but similar in concept. It still uses a forever loop as the core of the event loop but it does not run continuously (that would waste CPU time, heats up the CPU and drain batteries). Instead it blocks calling one of the asynchronous I/O API (select, poll, epoll, kqueue etc. - libuv will select at compile time) and passes control to the OS which would put the process to sleep until one of the registered I/O events is triggered.

Now, notice your code:

```
let doAsynchronousStuff = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("abcdefg"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)])
    }, Math.PI * 1 + Math.random())
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(doAsynchronousStuff)
}
```

I don't know about you but to me it is significantly easier to reason about than the traditional state machine. OK, for this very simple example the C pseudocode above is quite easy to understand but consider a real-world node.js or jQuery application with tens or hundreds of complex events (in the case of traditional jQuery apps, those events may even unschedule themselves or schedule even more event handlers). As the number of events you have to handle grow what javascript gives you in its syntax becomes far more readable even though for *one* event a beginner who's not familiar with anonymous functions and asynchronous code may prefer my pseudo-C example.

Even old-school non-promisified callbacks are more readable than the pseudo-C code:

```
function doAsynchronousStuff () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("abcdefg"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
      doAsynchronousStuff();
    }, Math.PI * 1 + Math.random());
}
```

So the syntax may be new (well, not that new, Lispers have been doing this sort of thing in the 70s) but the idea is old. The core concept may not be recognisable due to the syntax so don't get too distracted by the syntax. It's just scheduling to run something with a timer. And we simply call repeated scheduling **"repeated scheduling"** (both Google Calendar and Apple Calendar call them "repeat").

Comment: Can you include a recursive pattern with description at your answer, for comparison and disambiguation?